# Rでnnetがダウンロードできません

Tags: r

```
 install.packages("nnet")
Warning in install.packages :
   リポジトリー https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib に対する索引にアクセスできません :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
 パッケージを ‘C:/Users/mogul/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’ 中にインストールします 
 (‘lib’ が指定されていないため) 
Warning in install.packages :
   リポジトリー https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib に対する索引にアクセスできません :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘nnet’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
   リポジトリー https://cran.ism.ac.jp/bin/windows/contrib/4.2 に対する索引にアクセスできません :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
```

Comment: 現時点で `https://cran.ism.ac.jp` にアクセスできない(`ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`)ので、別のリポジトリからインストールしてみてはどうでしょうか。`install.packages("nnet", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")`

Comment: 解決しました、ありがとうございました。